# dump() function results in Out of Memory Exception

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working on a `Symfony 6` based project. During debugging I have added `{{ dump() }}` method to a twig template. This resulted in an `Out of Memory` exception. Even with the most basic template and controller the error is the same:

```
// .../SomeProject/src/Controller/TestController.php
class TestController extends AbstractController {
    public function dashboard(Request $request): Response {
        return $this->render('dump.html.twig');
    }    
}

// .../SomeProject/templates/Controller/dump.html.twig
{{ dump() }}


// Error    
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 17179869184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12882821120 bytes) in ...SomeProject/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/DebugExtension.php on line 57

Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in ...SomeProject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php on line 163
```

I have checked all services, controllers, etc. for possible recursive dependencies but I could find none. Additionally I am not sure, if recursive dependencies within services which are not involved in serving this request would even matter. **Do they?**

So, is this a (known) bug in Symfony (with a known workaround)? Or some error in my project? What steps to identify and resolve the problem could I perform?

### Edit

Some more information requested in the comments:

```
{{ dump() }}                  // out of memory
{{ dump(foo) }}               // string(15) "this is as test"
{{ foo }}                     // Variable " foo" does not exist.
{{ _context|keys|dump }}      // Unknown "dump" filter. Did you mean "yaml_dump"?
{{ _context|keys|yaml_dump }} // %array% [foo, app]
{{ _context|yaml_dump }}      // %array% { test: 'this is as test', app: null }
{{ dump(_context|keys) }}     // array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(3) "app" }
{{ dump(_context) }}          // out of memory
```

### Edit2

OK, the problem that `Variable " foo" does not exist.` is resolved. It seems that there was some illegal character instead of a space just before `{{ foo }}`. After fixing this, it outputs correctly.

However, the main question is still, why `dump()` does not work. In an old Symfony 3 project this works just fine and outputs a great overview of the complete context. This is pretty handy to see what information is available.

Comment: I mean why do you want to `dump` the full context? Did you try someting simple like `{{ dump(foo) }}`? Also I know you could install xdebug and then `dump` will use xdebug, possibly fixing the issue because by default `dump` uses `var_dump`

Comment: Dumping a single var like `{{ dump(foo) }}` works without any problem. However, twig shows me an error that one var which should be there is not defined. So I wanted to check the context so see what is actually in it. This resulted in the described error.

Comment: If i want to verify the variables in my templates, I'd go with `{{ _context|keys|dump }}` and then go from there

Comment: `twig shows me an error that one var which should be there is not defined` - Are you using macro's?

Comment: No, I do not use any macros. The error even occurs when I use the very, very simple template shown above. When trying to use the `|dump` filter, symfony reports it as being unknown and proposes to use `yaml_dump` instead.

Comment: Yeah sorry, try with `{{ dump(_context|keys) }}`

Comment: As your edit2: Cause it uses `var_dump` in the background. I suggest trying with xdebug